# droppedDueToLateness and droppedDueToClosedWindow in Dataflow

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

So far been playing with this for quite a while and I'm struggling to find the sweet spot regarding Window objects in Apache Beam.

```
Window.into(FixedWindows.of(Duration.standardMinutes(15)))
            .triggering(AfterWatermark
                .pastEndOfWindow())
            .withAllowedLateness(Duration.ZERO)
            .discardingFiredPanes()
```

My initial thought of a Window object which triggers each 15 minutes is the previous one. However, this approach gives me `droppedDueToLateness`. In order to solve this I thought "Ok, let's increase allowed lateness then!".

Modified the following line `.withAllowedLateness(Duration.standardMinutes(60))` so that late events can still make it within the Window.

However, after making this change, dropped events `droppedDueToClosedWindow` are back again, which are the ones I was trying to avoid in my initial implementations! (Not included in this question but not really related to the question).

Messages come from a PubSub queue with a timestamp event from the message payload itself (attribute within a JSON object, not the timestamp from PubSub).

Any cluse why this may be happening? Should I just increase resources or still tweak my Window object a little bit?

Answer (score 1):

I got a lot of droppedDueToClosedWindow and switched my Window to be very simple

```
Window.into(FixedWindows.of(windowDuration)))
```

Then they went away.

Looking at [Google's dataflow templates](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowTemplates/tree/master/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/teleport/templates) they use Windowing one of 2 ways.  The very simple way listed above. And in DLPTextToBigQueryStreaming they do the following which looks like what you were doing.  I have better success with the first approach.

```
                Window.<KV<String, ReadableFile>>into(FixedWindows.of(WINDOW_INTERVAL))
                .triggering(
                    AfterProcessingTime.pastFirstElementInPane().plusDelayOf(Duration.ZERO))
                .discardingFiredPanes()
                .withAllowedLateness(Duration.ZERO))
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you share the code where you read data from `PubSubIO`? Did you use the [`withTimestampAttribute`](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.16.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/gcp/pubsub/PubsubIO.Read.html#withTimestampAttribute-java.lang.String-) method?

Comment: I couldn't use that as the events are bytecoded, thus I would need to deserialize them and still it would be a JSON.

What I'm using to infer those timestamps (when decoding the JSON and retrieving that field info) is `WithTimestamps.of(new SetTimestampFn()).withAllowedTimestampSkew(new Duration(Long.MAX_VALUE)))`